# JsonProperty in java

Tags: java, jackson

I found this question in other questions, but I think they are too old and they are not working anymore.

I'm consuming an external service that returns a JSON and I want to convert it into an object in my own service. At the same time, this object will be my service output.

My problem is using JsonProperty, I would like to rename some variables I'm receiving in my json, but it is not working, somehow it works in debugger, but not in the returned object.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class MyClass {

  @JsonProperty("NAME")
  private String name;

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

}
```

So what I expect to receive is a json with a key name, but I get one with key NAME

```
// Expected:
{
   "name": "John"
}
// Received
{
   "NAME": "John"
}
```

As I can read in other solutions the problem is the import, some people are using old JsonProperty library, but I'm using the expecting one.

Is there anything else I should check to make it work?

Comment: A little bit unclear. Are you _reading_ a JSON? Or are you _producing_ a JSON? And is the problem that you have `NAME` in your JSON, but you want to have `name`? Or vice versa?

Comment: Why do you expect lowercase `"name"` when you explicitly specify the uppercase version using the annotation?

Answer (score 0):

So you are using an annotation making the response to have that "NAME" as a key. This is solely there to rename the JSON response keys. So removing it will let you get the key as "name"